# A bases for the product topology on $X\times Y$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> **Problem:** Let $\mathcal{B}_1$ be a basis for a topology $\mathcal{T}_1$ on a set $X$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ a basis for a topology $\mathcal{T}_2$ on a set $Y$. Prove that the collection of sets
> $\mathcal{B}:=\{B_1\times B_2: B_1\in\mathcal{B}_1\text{ and }B_2\in\mathcal{B}_2\}$ is a basis for a topology on $X\times Y$.

**Attempt:**
Since $\mathcal{B}_1$ be a basis for a topology $\mathcal{T}_1$ on a set $X$
$$
X=\bigcup_{B_1\in\mathcal{B}_1}B_1.
$$

Since $\mathcal{B}_2$ be a basis for a topology $\mathcal{T}_2$ on a set $Y$
$$
Y=\bigcup_{B_2\in\mathcal{B}_2}B_2.
$$

Therefore,

$$
X\times Y=\left(\bigcup_{B_1\in\mathcal{B}_1}B_1\right)\times\left(\bigcup_{B_2\in\mathcal{B}_2}B_2\right)=
\bigcup_{B_1\in\mathcal{B}_1,\\ B_2\in\mathcal{B}_2}(B_1\times B_2)=
\bigcup_{B\in\mathcal{B}}B.
$$

That is, $X\times Y$ is a union of members of $\mathcal{B}$.

Now let $B,B'\in\mathcal{B}$. Then $B=B_1\times B_2$ and $B'=B_1'\times B_2'$ for $B_1,B_1'\in\mathcal{B}_1$ and $B_2,B_2'\in\mathcal{B}_2$. Notice
$$
B\cap B'=(B_1\times B_2)\cap(B_1'\times B_2')=(B_1\cap B_1')\times(B_2\cap B_2').
$$

Since $\mathcal{B}_1$ is a basis and $B_1,B_1'\in\mathcal{B}_1$
$$
B_1\cap B_1'=\bigcup_{B_X\in\mathcal{B}_1}B_X.
$$

Since $\mathcal{B}_2$ is a basis and $B_2,B_2'\in\mathcal{B}_2$
$$
B_2\cap B_2'=\bigcup_{B_Y\in\mathcal{B}_2}B_Y.
$$

Therefore,
$$
B\cap B'=\left(\bigcup_{B_X\in\mathcal{B}_1}B_X\right)\times\left(\bigcup_{B_Y\in\mathcal{B}_2}B_Y\right)=
\bigcup_{B_X\in\mathcal{B}_1,\\ B_Y\in\mathcal{B}_2}(B_X\times B_Y)=
\bigcup_{B_{X,Y}\in\mathcal{B}}B_{X,Y}.
$$

That is, the intersection of any two members of $\mathcal{B}$ is the union of members of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: In general, $(A\cup B)\times (C\cup D)\neq (A\times C)\cup (B\times D)$, so the part where you show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a cover of $X\times Y$ is incorrect. For the second part, once you have $B\cap B'=(B_1\cap B_1')\times (B_2\cap B_2')$, you can stop because $B_1\cap B_1'\in\mathcal{B}_1$ and $B_2\cap B_2'\in\mathcal{B}_2$ so $B\cap B'\in\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Instead you should show that $X\times Y\subseteq\mathcal{B}$. So let $(x,y)\in X\times Y$. Then $x\in B_1$ and $y\in B_2$ for some $B_1\in\mathcal{B}_1$ and for some $B_2\in\mathcal{B}_2$. Now what can you say about where $(x,y)$ lives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much simpler than using all these formulae, just reason pointwise:

- Let $(x,y) \in X \times Y$. Then $x \in B_1 \in \mathcal{B}_1$ for some $B_1$ and $y \in B_2 \in \mathcal{B}_2$ for some $B_2$ and then $(x,y) \in B_1 \times B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$. So $\mathcal{B}$ covers $X \times Y$.
- Suppose $(x,y) \in B \cap B'$ where $B, B' \in \mathcal{B}$ so we have $B_1, B_1' \in \mathcal{B}_1$ and $B_2, B'_2 \in \mathcal{B}_2$ with $B= B_1 \times B_2, B' = B'_1 \times B_2'$. Then $x \in B_1 \cap B'_1$ and as this is open in $X$ there is some $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}_1$ such that $x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B'_2$. Similarly, there is $B'_3 \in \mathcal{B}'_2$ so that $y \in B_3' \subseteq B_2 \cap B_2'$. It follows that $(x,y) \in B_3 \times B'_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ and $B_3 \times B_3' \subseteq B \cap B'$, as required.

QED