# Proving that the following basis generates a topology on the product space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, product-space

I'm working through John M. Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds and am trying to complete exercise 3.25. In this exercise, we are asked to show that if $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are arbitrary topological spaces then
$$ \mathcal{B} = \{ U_1 \times \cdots \times U_n : U_i \text{ is an open subset of }X_i, i = 1,2,3,\dots,n \}  $$

is the basis for a topology on $X = X_1 \times \cdots \times X_n$.

**My attempt so far**

To show that $\mathcal B$ generates a topology, we must show

1. $\cup_{B \in \mathcal B} B = X$.
2. For any $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal B$ and any $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, there exists some $B_3 \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

*To show requirement 1*, we can show set containment in both directions.

Suppose $x = (p_1, \dots, p_n) \in X = X_1 \times \cdots \times X_n$. So, $p_i \in X_i$. Then, for each $p_i$ there exists some set $U_i^{p_i}$ open in $X_i$ st $x \in U_i^{p_1}$. So, $x \in U_1^{p_1} \times \cdots \times U_n^{p_n} = B_x$. This holds for any point $x \in X$, so clearly, $X \subseteq \cup_{B \in \mathcal B} B$.

On the other hand, suppose $x = (p_1, \dots, p_n) \in \cup_{B \in \mathcal B} B$. Then there is some $B_x = U_1^{p_1} \times \cdots \times U_n^{p_n} $ such that $p_i \in U_i^{p_i}$ and $U_i^{p_i} \subseteq X_i$. So, certainly, we have $x \in X$. This shows $\cup_{B \in \mathcal B} B \subseteq X$. Thus, the two are equal.

*To show requirement 2*, suppose we have $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal B$ and $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$. We can write $x = (p_1, \dots, p_n) $, and express the basis sets as $B_1 = U_1 \times \cdots U_n$, $B_2 = V_1 \times \cdots \times V_n$ where $U_i$'s and $V_i$'s are open sets in $X_i$.

Then, $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ means that $p_i \in U_i \cap V_i$. Since each $U_i, V_i$ is open, the intersection $W_i = U_i \cap V_i \subseteq X_i$ is itself open in $X_i$. Then, we can write $x \in B_3 = (W_1, \dots, W_n) \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

This shows the second requirement is fulfilled, and so $\mathcal B$ generates a topology (the product topology) on $X$.

**My question** is whether or not my argument for requirement 2 is valid. I feel like there is something subtle i'm misunderstanding here. Any corrections or suggestions in general would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks ok to me

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130156/a-bases-for-the-product-topology-on-x-times-y?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for the response and link!

Answer (score 1):

The proof is ok. Actually, you can simplify the proof of *requirement 1* noting that the inclusion $\subseteq$ is obvious as clearly every $B$ is contained an $X$, so the same is true for the union.